# storing boolean values in elasticsearch : optimization?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, boolean

I have json documents with entries like :

`......`

`{`

`"Fieldname" : "booked",`

`"Fieldvalue" : "yes"`

`}`

`...`

Within the json document, there are many fields like this, where Boolean value is indirectly mentioned using Fieldname and Fieldvalue : Essentially it signifies that booked=true. Would it be more efficient to transform the json before storing it in elasticsearch ? I.e. replacing the above with :

`{`

`"booked" : true`

`}`

? The search use case is that I want to figure out whether similar json already exists in the system before adding another json.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the later one is much cleaner way to **store** and **search** purpose both. Say you want to get all the booked properties from your index then you can easily do this way instead of using extra **Fieldname** and **Fieldvalue**

```
GET /properties/_search
{
  "size": 10, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "country_code.keyword": "US"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "booked": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "usd_price": {
              "gte": 50,
              "lte": 100000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "ranking": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "_source": [
    "property_id",
    "property_name",
    "country",
    "country_code",
    "state",
    "state_abbr",
    "city"

  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sunny. The second approach is cleaner,  but does it also have any practical effects : e.g. the score when querying , or significant effect on CPU cycles if querying/filtering a lot?

Comment: I don't think not very much mate but I think it will impact on query, storage when you are going to store huge dataset e.g 10M or more. Also the later one is less typing. Because with formar approach, you've to use 2 match for one booked:true